# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud instance, which connects to a google cloud SQL database. This morning the connection was lost, and I recieved the following error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'

The connection was up and running for one month now end without any change, the connection was lost.
I tried restarting the SQL instance several times, but without any luck.
Als on the google Cloud Developers Console, the page databases (on my sql instance), won't show. (error: Failed to load)

I think it's a connection failure at google, But how to be sure?

Both cloud instance and SQl instance are on zone europe.

Thanks

Comment: If you are connecting to CloudSQL from GCE instace can you make sure tcp_keepalive is set to 60 secs on your GCE instance (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#communicatewithinternet).

Answer (score 1):

There are several Cloud SQL issues that can cause `Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'`.  The most common are:

- Connecting from an IP or GAE app that is not [authorized on the ACL.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control)
- You have reached one of the [connection limits](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq?hl=en#sizeqps).
- Your instance has an activation policy of `NEVER`.
- This can also temporarily happen while an instance is being restarted.